# Android open app switcher programmatically

Tags: java, android, qt

Is there a way to open the app switcher programmatically in Java?
I've managed to handle the home button by invoking

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
```

but I haven't find anything on how to handle the app switch button.
I need to handle these buttons because on my device (PAX A920), using Qt, the os is not intercepting them.